# Fit rectangles of fixed area into a larger rectangle

Tags: javascript

I have a large rectangle which is 10*10, an area of 100. I'm looking for a way to fit, for example: 6 rectangles of a fixed area into an area of 10*10.

The 6 rectangles have a fixed area, but do not have a fixed width/height. Their areas will always add up to 100, so it's really a percentage of the larger area.

I don't want to have 1 row and just change the width of each rectangle. I would like a way of placing the rectangles in the most efficient way that tries to keep them as close to a square as possible.

Thank you.

-Solved-

Comment: Im not sure if this would be helpful but google 2D bin packing algorithm youll find plenty of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this, so I'll just give an example of a simple to understand (if somewhat inefficient) method that should still give fairly decent results.

1. Start by ordering your boxes from largest to smallest.
2. Presume that your first box is going to be square (it won't end up that way, but it will end close).  Take `sqrt(area[1])` to get the length of its side.  Take that width as the width you want for your first column.
3. Given that width, fill as many more rows as you can in that column.
4. Add up how much total area you have put in the column; resize its width to be match that (it will now be a little thinner).
5. Repeat steps 1-3 for the rest of the available boxes.  When you get to the point where the target width for your first box in the column is wider than the amount of space you have left, just use that width.
6. The remaining boxes should cleanly fit into that remaining space in that column.

This will give you aligned columns, with varying height divisions.  As an alternative, you can flip "row" and "column" to get constant row divisions with varying column splits.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: hmm, I just tried to do it, and even though the rectangles are the correct area, there's always a random width of the overall larger rectangle. I'm not sure where the extra area comes and goes .-.

Comment: Not sure why exactly it happens, but I just changed the widths of all the boxes at the end so that they fit inside.